# SQL select everything in an array of many values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an array with 20 values and I'd like to select all rows that contains that values but I don't know how to do it.

Here is the array:

```
idList = ["tt11866324","tt1649418","tt12593682","tt4614584","tt10954984","tt6718412","tt10648342","tt1655389","tt10298810","tt14814040","tt1745960","tt8912936","tt7144666","tt6710474","tt9411972","tt12262116","tt3704428","tt7214954","tt8041270","tt16491324"]
```

The table where I'd like to select is called "content".

Can anyone help me, please?

Update: It is about MariaDB, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE id IN ("tt11866324","tt1649418","tt12593682","tt4614584","tt10954984","tt6718412","tt10648342","tt1655389","tt10298810","tt14814040","tt1745960","tt8912936","tt7144666","tt6710474","tt9411972","tt12262116","tt3704428","tt7214954","tt8041270","tt16491324")
```